# How to deal with removing some words out of lists of text list if text list and remove word list are huge

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-efficient

By using Python, I would like to remove some of the words from the texts, which consist of lists of list as shown below (e.g. text_list consists of 5 texts, which of each consists of around 4 to 8 words, along with the remove words list of 5 words):

```
text_list = [["hello", "how", "are", "you", "fine", "thank", "you"],
             ["good", "morning", "have", "great", "breakfast"],
             ["you", "are", "a", "student", "I", "am", "a", "teacher"],
             ["trump", "it", "is", "a", "fake", "news"],
             ["obama", "yes", "we", "can"]]

remove_words = ["hello", "breakfast", "a", "obama", "you"]
```

This is a really simple issue when you are dealing with the small data like above, as shown below:

```
new_text_list = list()
for text in text_list:
    temp_list = list()
    for word in text:
        if word not in remove_words:
            temp_list.append(word)
    new_text_list.append(temp_list)
```

but when it comes to huge data like consisting of more than 10,000 texts, which of each also consists of more than 1,000 words, along with the remove word list of more than 20,000 words, I am wondering how you could deal with such a situation. Isn't there any efficient Python code that could produce the same results or any multicore processing program or so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a `set` for `remove_words`, which has constant-time membership tests, vs a `list`,which has linear-time membership tests. Then it should be significantly faster.

Comment: Thank you so much, it does really increase the speed of processing removing words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two basic techniques for speeding up your process are

1) A `set` object has a (mostly) linear access time when testing for inclusion whereas a `list` object needs to loop through as much as the entire list so it is dependent on the list size (iow, inclusion test time grows proportionately with the size of the list)

2) Avoid making intermediate collections if you can, using generators and comprehensions when you can so that they are lazily evaluated

Here's an example that employs both approaches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

text_list = [["hello", "how", "are", "you", "fine", "thank", "you"],
             ["good", "morning", "have", "great", "breakfast"],
             ["you", "are", "a", "student", "I", "am", "a", "teacher"],
             ["trump", "it", "is", "a", "fake", "news"],
             ["obama", "yes", "we", "can"]]

# use a set() for remove words because testing for inclusion is much faster than a long list
# removed two of your original bad words so I could make sure it passed some
remove_words = set(["hello", "breakfast", "obama"])

#make a generator, rather than a list, because why not?
result = (sentence for sentence in text_list if all(word not in remove_words for word in sentence))

for acceptable in result:
    print(acceptable)
```

Comment: Aside. If you end up testing this on your original inputs, I'm curious just how much faster it runs.

Comment: If the one line generator isn't entirely clear, I can break it down better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting each subarray in alphabetical order, and then calling a binary search on each subarray to find the corresponding elements that you would like to remove. It should speed up the process!

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate on that? Giving some example Python code would be really helpful!

Comment: let's say we have: 

arr = [['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a']] 
removeArr = ['b', 'a', 'c']

we could so something like: 

for subArr in arr : 
    sort(subArr)
    for i in removeArr :
        index = binary_search(subArr, i)
        pop(index) 

python should have a built-in binary search function which takes in an array and element that you want to find in the array. 

let me know if this makes sense!

Comment: sorry for the previous comments - I'm still new to stack overflow so I was having some trouble using it.